# Convert Poorly Formed String to DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have the following string:

```
Updated: 15:14 03/10
```

I wish to convert it to datetime format in order to insert it into a datetime field within sql server.

```
string date = 'Updated: 15:14 03/10';
    string updatedTime = date.Split(' ')[0];
    string updatedDate = date.Split(' ')[1];
    string updatedMonth = updatedDate.Split('/')[1];
    string updatedDay = updatedDate.Split('/')[0];
    string updatedYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year.ToString();
    string updated = updatedYear + '-' + updatedMonth + '-' + updatedDay + ' ' + updatedTime;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(updated);
```

Is this there a cleaner / more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the correct [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  Something like this:

```
string date = "Updated: 15:14 03/10";
string modifiedDate = date.Replace("Updated: ", "");
string format = "HH:mm dd/MM";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(modifiedDate, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

**Edit** Actually, you don't need the year in the format string; the DateTime parser is smart enough to assume the current year.

**Edit #2** If you wanted to get cheeky, you could include the "Updated" part in the format string.  It's a bit ugly though, because you need to escape the characters `d`, `t`, and `:`.

```
string date = "Updated: 15:14 03/10";
string format = @"Up\da\te\d\: HH:mm dd/MM";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is *always* that form? If so, it looks like you should be able to do:

```
string trimmed = text.Substring("Updated: ".Length);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(trimmed, "HH:mm dd/MM",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's possible that this would work too, but I haven't tried it:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "'Updated: 'HH:mm dd/MM",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's not clear whether you're expecting the result to be local or UTC, by the way - you can specify various options via `DateTimeStyles`.